# how to embed html text in Flex TextArea

Tags: html, xml, textarea, flex3, embedding

I have a panel on which I have put fadeIn show effect. At first, the effect was only applied to the panel. The text would just appear without the fadeIn effect. Then someone here told me to embed the fonts, which worked like a charm

Now I have another problem: I get the text posted to the rich text editor and then I ake the HTML Text and post it to my panel. Now the embedding doesn't work! Either it just appears without the fadeIn, or, if I embed it, it doesn't show up at all!

How can I save data with HTML formatting in XML and retrieve the data and get the same HTML formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're just enabling the embedFonts property, but not actually embedding the fonts themselves. The font resources need to be embedded at compile time, or loaded and registered at runtime.

See [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=fonts_04.html) for compile time embedding, and [here](http://nochump.com/blog/archives/20) and [here](http://www.visible-form.com/blog/dynamically-loading-fonts-at-runtime/) for runtime loading.